# Method signature and error handling within Project Reactor

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, project-reactor

Kind of running around in circles trying to handle a scenario that I might just not be looking at it the "reactive" way of simply need a break to see the bigger picture.

Lets say I want to save a user to the database but first I need to see if a person with that name exists, so:

Repository using `ReactiveCrudRepository`

```kotlin
interface UserRepository : ReactiveCrudRepository<User, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE name = :name LIMIT 1")
    fun findByName(name: String): Mono<User>

    fun saveUser(user: User): Mono<User>

}
```

Business code

```kotlin
fun saveUser(user: User): Mono<User> {
  return repository.findByName(user.name)
    .flatMap { existingUser ->
      return Mono.error(UserExistsException())  //A Mono<User> is expected 
    }
    .switchIfEmpty {
      return repository.saveUser(user)
    }
}
```

The fact that the repository returns Mono.empty() on nulls (that is, if no user with that name is found) seems to limit the way I can handle the case where the user already exists, because I wanted to throw the error so the caller deals with this in his way.

I tried to return a `Mono<Optional<User>>` on the repository side so I never get an `empty` but the library does not allow this.

I'm new to reactive in general and I wanted to keep things simple but also within the good practices, so how should I approach this? Is `flatMap` what I want here? I need to return a User on success and ideally an exception on failures, but I can't simply throw inside `flatMap` since it asks for a `Mono<User>`

Comment: Your logic is fine. The problem comes from the `return` keyword inside lambda. In Kotlin, [using `return` in a lambda is a corner case](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/returns.html#return-to-labels). You should just remove both return in lambdas, and it will work.

Comment: Watch out for a race condition: what happens if someone else creates a user after you check if the user exists, but before you create it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Kotlin, unlike Java, `return` is not used inside lambdas. This is only allowed inside `inline` lambdas for *early return*.

Besides that there are two more issues with your code:

1. `switchIfEmpty` accepts a `Mono` value, but not a lambda.
2. `Mono.error` requires a generic argument of `T`.

So here is the fixed code:

```kotlin
fun saveUser(user: User): Mono<User> =
    repository.findByName(user.name)
        .flatMap { existingUser ->
            Mono.error<User>(UserExistsException())
        }.switchIfEmpty(repository.saveUser(user))
```

If you're working with Kotlin however with Spring, it's recommended to use Coroutines and avoid Project Reactor if possible. To do so we can redefine the `UserRepository` using `CoroutineCrudRepository` instead of `ReactiveCrudRepository`.

```kotlin
import org.springframework.data.repository.kotlin.CoroutineCrudRepository

interface UserRepository : CoroutineCrudRepository<User, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE name = :name LIMIT 1")
    suspend fun findByName(name: String): User?

    suspend fun saveUser(user: User): User
}
```

The resulting code also looks much nicer.

```kotlin
suspend fun saveUser(user: User): User {
    val foundUser = repository.findByName(user.name)
    return if (foundUser == null) repository.saveUser(user)
    else throw UserExistsException()
}
```

Comment: I'm also quite basic with Kotlin so I never really touched suspend or coroutines. Thanks for the guide, I'll see what I can do about switching to Coroutines, never got user to the reactive model anyway and this looks more in line with async/await